# Split dataframe into many dataframes by columns

Tags: r, lm

I would like to do lm on a dataframe using variables in the first 3 columns, but excluding rows where there are NAs in another column (say column 5). (I need this to do anova later on). I need to do lm reiteratively, each time excluding a different set of rows containing NA in a different column (e.g. column 6, 7, 8 ...). The real data frame has 100,000 columns x 200,000 rows and will require lm to be run ~100000 times. 
Suppose I want to run lm(pheno~Chip+Sex+Height, data=My_df) but exclude rows where there is NA in the rs533317162_T.x column? Then I would want to do the same but exclude rows where there is NA in the next column (rs550410894_C.x).

My_df:

```
Sex Height Age  pheno rs533317162_T.x rs550410894_C.x rs563620164_C.x rs10465242_G.x
2  161.0  50 -0.557               0               0               0              0
2  170.0  69  1.757               0               0               0              0
2  166.0  52  1.262              NA               0               0              0
1  171.0  68  0.144               0               0               0              0
1  178.0  66  0.034               0               0               0              0
2  156.0  54  0.098              NA               0               0              0
2  157.0  61  1.706               0               0               0              0
1  182.0  62 -0.651               1               0               1              1
2  162.0  57 -0.920               0               0               0              0
2  163.0  51  2.237               0               0               0              0
2  165.0  48 -0.294               0               0               0              0
2  167.0  42 -0.911               1               0               0              0
1  180.0  64 -0.717              NA               0               1              1
```

list of columns:

```
SNP <- c("rs533317162_T.x", "rs550410894_C.x", "rs563620164_C.x", "rs10465242_G.x")
```

The lm function:

```
My_lms <- lapply(1:4, function(x)
lm(pheno~Sex+Height+Age, data = subset(My_df, !is.na(SNP[[x]]))))
```

This returns all rows for each of the four lms. The rows with the NAs in the SNP columns are still used in the lm. If I manually type in the column name instead of SNP[[x]], it work and excludes rows with NAs. I have also tried a similar approach with weights in the lm formula, but with no success. I think the problem is that SNP[[x]] is not being used or read.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I can't reproduce your issue. If I do

```
fit <- lapply(5:8, function(x)
    lm(pheno ~ Sex + Height + Age, data = subset(df, !is.na(df[x]))));
```

then `lm` uses only those rows from `df` where there is no `NA` in the relevant column (here, columns `5-8`).

You can confirm this by looking at the number of rows of the `subset`ted `df`:

```
dms <- sapply(5:8, function(x)
        nrow(subset(df, !is.na(df[x]))));
dms;
#[1] 10 13 13 13
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Sex Height Age  pheno rs533317162_T.x rs550410894_C.x rs563620164_C.x rs10465242_G.x
2  161.0  50 -0.557               0               0               0              0
2  170.0  69  1.757               0               0               0              0
2  166.0  52  1.262              NA               0               0              0
1  171.0  68  0.144               0               0               0              0
1  178.0  66  0.034               0               0               0              0
2  156.0  54  0.098              NA               0               0              0
2  157.0  61  1.706               0               0               0              0
1  182.0  62 -0.651               1               0               1              1
2  162.0  57 -0.920               0               0               0              0
2  163.0  51  2.237               0               0               0              0
2  165.0  48 -0.294               0               0               0              0
2  167.0  42 -0.911               1               0               0              0
1  180.0  64 -0.717              NA               0               1              1", header = T)
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help @stuartkim. You can close the question by accepting an answer and setting the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

Subset is probably looking for a variable called `SNP` in your dataframe. Rather than use subset just use a check on the dataframe like the below. We return My_df, but use those values of SNP[x] which aren't NA to index the rows we return in My_df.

```
My_lm <- lapply(1:4, function(x){
                           lm(pheno~Sex+Height+Age, data = My_df[!is.na(My_df[,SNP[x]]),]
                           }
```

To break this down further, `!is.na(My_df[,SNP[x]])` is the bit that returns TRUEs and FALSEs for those which aren't NA in column `SNP[x]`. Say we said `result = !is.na(My_df[,SNP[x]])`, then we are just using `data = My_df[result,]`, this then gives us just the rows of data we want.